# A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed error in a synchronous asp.net identity call

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity-2

I am getting

> "A second operation started on this context before a previous
>   asynchronous operation completed"

error intermittently in an MVC project that uses asp.net identity 2.1. Basically I have a base controller where every other controller derives from, and this controller has a property that returns an ApplicationUser. (The extended class of asp.net identity user). The base controller has the following. Note that UserManager is retrieved from the OwinContext (and yes, it is created by using

> CreatePerOwinContext()

method, just like in the templates.

```
protected ApplicationUser ApplicationUser
    {
        get
        {
            var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var applicationUser = UserManager.FindById(userId);
            if (applicationUser == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return applicationUser;
        }
    }

protected ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
```

Then in my other controllers, I freely call this property to get a reference to the ApplicationUser, an example being as follows

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var model = new OrganizationListViewModel(false)
            {
                OrganizationDetailViewModels = ApplicationUser.Affiliations
                   .Select(e => new OrganizationDetailViewModel(
                                e.Organization, ApplicationUser)).ToList()
            };
            return View(model);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Search", "Search", new { type = "organization" });
        }
    }
```

This sometimes works, and sometimes it gives the error I mentioned. I am not calling an async operation in the property or the controller method. So I am puzzled. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect this line:

```
OrganizationDetailViewModels = ApplicationUser.Affiliations
               .Select(e => new OrganizationDetailViewModel(
                            e.Organization, ApplicationUser)).ToList()
```

Here you do a request for `ApplicationUser`, then lazy-load `Affiliations`, then for every select in `Affiliations` you do a request for `ApplicationUser` again.

Do local caching for the `ApplicationUser` to avoid multiple requests to DB where only one is required:

```
private ApplicationUser _cachedUser;
protected ApplicationUser ApplicationUser
{
    get
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        if (_cachedUser == null)
        {
            var applicationUser = UserManager.FindById(userId);
            return applicationUser;
        }
        return _cachedUser;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I missed the caching implementation. It definitely avoids the calls to FindById() within the same request so I didn't get the error anymore. However, I am still surprised by the error. There are no async operations within the call stack at all, so not sure why it complains about async operations. It was just bad in terms of performance but mention of a "previous async operation" within the error is still puzzling. If you have any input, I would love to hear. Thank you for your response

Comment: Identity uses async ops by default. And the sync `FindById` you are using is coming from an extension that just wraps async calls into sync wrapper. And the exception comes from EF DbContext that checks on multiple async ops. Something along these lines.